# Tensorflow: How to check the validation accuracy every 100 iterations?

Tags: validation, tensorflow

I try to use the following code to check the validation accuracy every 100 iterations, however, the validation accuracy is not changing(the network is fine)

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(1000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_:batch[1], keep_prob:1.0})
        print('step %d, training accuracy %g' %(i, train_accuracy))
        validation_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images, y_:mnist.test.labels, keep_prob:0.0})
        print('step %d, validation accuracy %g' %(i, validation_accuracy))

    train_step.run(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_:batch[1], keep_prob:0.5})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't added your network implementation, my answer will be an educated guess.

**TL;DR**: You should use `keep_prob:1.0` instead of `keep_prob:0.0` in your validation step.

By the appearance of `keep_prob`, I deduce that your network is using [dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout). By using `feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images, y_:mnist.test.labels, keep_prob:0.0}`, you are feeding a `0.0` probability to keeping an activation, which is equivalent to a `1.0` probability of dropping it. The result is that when you are performing validation, you are basically ignoring the input to the network and all hidden layers. This has the effect that the last layer gives you the same output values for all classes of MNIST (this may be only approximately true, depending on the specific implementation), therefore the accuracy is constant.

Dropout is a method for regularization, which drops neurons during training steps, thus improving the generalization ability of the network. When you are not training (such as during a validation step), you want to keep all neurons. Thus, what you probably want to do is feed the value `1.0` instead.